# How does passing two style() functions work, when passed into the query() function for Angular Animations?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Being pretty new to angular animations, I have read angular.io animation docs a couple times over to get an idea how it all works. I think I have a decent understanding, however there are some scenarios that the docs do not explain.

Given this starter [project](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter), I had a question regarding their use of the `query()` method with multiple `style()` functions.

In the above referenced github project in the [this file](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter/blob/master/src/app/core/animations/route.animations.ts) there is an animation used that I could not find any explanations online.

`

```
query(
      ':leave > *',
      [
        style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)', opacity: 1 }),
        animate(
          '0.2s ease-in-out',
          style({ transform: 'translateY(-3%)', opacity: 0 })
        ),
        style({ position: 'fixed' })
      ],
      { optional: true }
    )
```

`

My understanding is that the first `style()` function passed into the `query()` function, sets the initial style for any element that is leaving and any of its child elements, denoted with the `:leave > *`. The `animate()` function will then animate this element over time `0.2s ease-in-out` with the provided `style()`. BUT what does the last `style({ position: 'fixed' })` supposed to do???

I can remove it, and I do not find any visible changes. I can modify the passed in object to `style({ background: 'red' })`, and I do not fin any visible changes. What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out.

The short version:

The reason for the last `style({ position: 'fixed' })` is to take the element that is leaving (the component in this case) and make sure it does not effect styling of other incoming elements.

The long version:

The new element (or component) that is entering the DOM is still 'sharing' the view or the 'document flow' with the element (or component) that is leaving the DOM. This means, that two elements (or component) are part of the normal document flow, even though the old element (or component) is not visible. This means if we have footer that is supposed to appear below the new element (or component) will not be displayed right below the new component, rather it will appear at the bottom of the document, right after the old element which has not yet been removed from the DOM. Once the old element has been removed and we did NOT use the third last 'style({ position: 'fixed' })' property, we would have a delay in seeing the footer being displayed right below the new element.

Position 'fixed' moves the old and at this point invisible element out of the document flow, leaving room for the new element and the footer to be displayed as expected.

This can be easily tested with changing the

```
`style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)', opacity: 1 }),
              animate(
                and increasing the time==>'1.2s ease-out',
                style({ transform: 'translateY(-3%)', opacity: 1 <== this })
              ),`
```

to see what is really happening. I hope this helps someone out!